# npm list strange behavior in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, npm

Compare these two commands in PowerShell (existing packages not needed)

**Version:**

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  1
```

---

1. `npm ls --depth 0`

> `-- (empty)` > **instant response**

---

2. `Measure-Command { npm ls --depth 0 }`

> `TotalSeconds      : 68,7934637` > **takes a decade of time**

---

Exact these behavior I receive for every npm command in PowerShell ISE if I use them inside a script.

Any workaround to run it normal timed?

Comment: Tested it on PowerShell console host (PSVersion 5.1.18362.145,  PSVersion 6.2.0), command takes 0.9 seconds. Also tested it inside a script and executed script from PowerShell ISE (Version: 5.1.18362.145) -> command takes ~ 0.9 seconds again.

Comment: @Moerwald thanks for your experience, on a second machine I get the same result like you. hm. :/

Comment: If you are curious, you could run `procmon` to try and find out what is causing the delay.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers could you give me a hint how to use `procmon`?

Comment: Start procmon -> Filter (Ctrl+L)  -> Process Name is PowerShell_ISE.exe -> Add/OK -> Run your test. Either there is a big delay between two lines, or you'll see too much being done, compared to your working machine. Depending on that outcome, you might have to investigate further.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers isn't `npm` an executable? If so, add "Process Name is npm.exe" to the filter list as well

Comment: @MarTin - np. Did you manage to find the issue?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers thanks for explaining me how to use procmon. I compare both commands (`npm ls --depth 0` = `fast`, `Measure-Command { npm ls --depth 0 }` = `slow`) could investigate the following: `fast` contains 323 events and need about **3** sec. `slow` has **342** events and need for **321** events the same time like `fast`. For the last **21** events `slow` needs additionally **83** sec.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers The **21** events consist of only two different event types: `"powershell.exe","7576","Thread Create","","SUCCESS","Thread ID: 24364"` and `"powershell.exe",7576","Thread Exit","","SUCCESS","Thread ID: 14368, User Time: 0.0000000, Kernel Time: 0.0000000"` and it allways switch between these two events. Therefore are only two different **PIDs** involved: `7576` and `8316` with always variable Thread **IDs**. I can see the delay but honestly that information do not say me a lot. What could be the reason?

Comment: @MarTin - did you save the events to a PML file? Can you share that file?

Comment: I save it as csv: [Slow.CSV](https://github.com/Nusserdt/Stackoverflow/blob/master/Slow.CSV) and [Fast.CSV](https://github.com/Nusserdt/Stackoverflow/blob/master/Fast.CSV). Hoster is: https://github.com